# Easiest way to send text from HTML to a .swf element

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

I was trying to send 4 paragraphs to a .swf element. I have no idea how to what to do. I tried using FlashVars but I feel like i need to drop in some actionscript to be able to work with the vars

```
conceptsNdisciplinesPar=(some text)&cultures&countriesPar=(some text) etc...
```

Is there an easy way to get access to this text in my .swf?

Answer (score 1):

If you are successfully embedding the flash vars into your HTML embed, then yes, you can access those values from within the SWF:

```
for (var flashVar:String in stage.loaderInfo.parameters)
{
    trace(flashVar+":"+stage.loaderInfo.parameters[flashVar]);
}
```

Note, you'll need a reference to the stage for this to work.  It's usually always available, but I have sometimes run into situations where my SWF needs to listen for the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event before using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

`ExternalInterface.callBack;` is the best way to send data from html to .swf.

for more to know about `externalInterface` click [here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)